# Representing an unsigned 32-bit value with two unsigned 16-bit integers

Tags: swift

How can I represent a `UInt32` with two `UInt16` numbers in Swift, and vice versa?

For example, the `UInt32` 65536 should be (UInt16) 1 and (UInt16) 65535, and (UInt16) 0 and (UInt16) 65533 combine to (UInt32) 65533

Comment: I'm more interested about Swift implementation

Comment: @JoshCaswell Not so much. A bit shift and an OR/AND.

Comment: And explicit type conversion in Swift, @Sulthan, which isn't necessary in ObjC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple bitwise operations

```
var number1: UInt16 = 1
var number2: UInt16 = 65535
let number: UInt32 = UInt32(number1) << 16 | UInt32(number2) 

number1 = UInt16(number >> 16)
number2 = UInt16(number & 0xFFFF)
```

Comment: Thanks i figured out myself little bit later than you provided this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
func toInt16(value:UInt32)->(UInt16,UInt16){
    return (UInt16(value >> 16),UInt16(value & UInt32(UInt16.max)))
}

func toInt32(value1:UInt16,value2:UInt16)->UInt32{
    return (UInt32(value1) << 16 | UInt32(value2))
}
```